# pass default credentials to BigQuery using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a new table in BigQuery. I have followed these instructions https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-bigquery-nodejs/index.html?index=..%2F..index#9 and have my user and roles defined properly.

I created a node project, installed the google dependencies and have the following code:

```
 const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
 const bigquery = new BigQuery({
   projectId: 'myproject-develop-3fcb6',
  private_key_id: "11111111111",
  client_email: "myuser-bigquery-sa@myproject-develop-3fcb6.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  client_id: "212111112",
  });
```

This is how im creating my dataset and table:

```
 module.exports = {
  createTable: ({ datasetId, tableId, schema, partitionBy}) => {
    const options = { schema };
    if (partitionBy) {
     options.timePartitioning = {
     field: partitionBy
   };
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve();
     bigquery
    .dataset(datasetId)
    .createTable(tableId, options)
    .then(results => resolve(results[0]))
    .catch(err => {
      handleError(err);
      reject(err);
    });
   });
  },
 };
```

When i run my createTableFunction and pass in the data set name, table name, schema I get the following error immediately

```
ERROR: Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
```

How do I pass my default credentials to BigQuery so i can perform CRUD operations in node.js? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the tutorial that you mentioned, this gcloud command creates a key.json:

```
   gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ~/key.json --iam-account  my-bigquery-sa@${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Then you can use the following code:

```
 // Create a BigQuery client explicitly using service account credentials.
 // by specifying the private key file.
 const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

 const options = {
   keyFilename: 'path/to/key.json',
   projectId: 'my_project',
 };

const bigquery = new BigQuery(options);
```

[Authenticating With a Service Account Key File](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file)

I do not know where are you running your code, but in the tutorial is a line where you set the env variable therefore you do not need to authenticate using the key.json file in your code:

```
   export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/${USER}/key.json"
```

> GCP client libraries use a strategy called Application Default
>   Credentials (ADC) to find your application's credentials. When your
>   code uses a client library, the strategy checks for your credentials
>   in the following order:
>
> First, ADC checks to see if the environment variable
>   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is set. If the variable is set, ADC
>   uses the service account file that the variable points to. The next
>   section describes how to set the environment variable.
>
> If the environment variable isn't set, ADC uses the default service
>   account that Compute Engine, Kubernetes Engine, Cloud Run, App Engine,
>   and Cloud Functions provide, for applications that run on those
>   services.
>
> If ADC can't use either of the above credentials, an error occurs.

Comment: downloaded key.json from GCP. that was my problem. I copied the contents from the terminal. big no-no. Thanks

Comment: You can also pass credentials directly as parameters.                                         
 ```                                                                                                                                  const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

 const options = {
   credentials: <content of key.json file>, // object is expected
   projectId: 'my_project',
 };
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also pass credentials directly as parameters.

```js
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery'); 

const bigQuery = new BigQuery({ 
  projectId: "your-prject-id",
  credentials: {...}, // content of json file 
});
```

*Thanks to [@MahendraPatel comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60155611/pass-default-credentials-to-bigquery-using-nodejs/74458937#comment127999485_60157291).*